# Django how to know if a method is instance method or class method

Tags: python, django

How do I know if a method in Django is an **instance method** or a **class method**, so that when overriding, I will know to put in "self".

For example: the method get_object(self, QuerySet=None) is an instance method because there is "self". However, in Django official doc, they do not explicitly write out "self" (Please see the link to the picture.) Thus, I do not know if get_object() is an instance method.
[link to the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrxIv.png)

I work on VScode, and VScode doesn't have good autocompletion to show the template of get_object(self, QuerySet=None). So then again, there is no way for me to find out get_object() is an instance method.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: If you use `help(ListView.get_queryset)` it will show the `self` parameter, since then it is not implicitly passed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So then I have to open a python REPL, import the method to be checked everytime I want to check something is a class/instance method. Is there any faster way please? I came from Java where there is code suggestion by the IDE that immediately tells me how to use the method. And it is so vague in Python, VScode in particular does not suggest the signature of the method. Anyway I really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve. Why do you need to check? To call it? Do you know how python looks for the method/attributes? Do you know what the `classmethod` decorator does? Just asking in order to understand. Please post more details

Comment: @Pynchia I don't have a goal to achieve in particular. I am learning Django as a beginner. I need to check to know get_object() is an instance/class so that when I override it, I can write the syntax properly. So I already know that get_object() is an instance method, but I am asking in general how can we know, because the code completion/ suggestion of VScode for python is not good. So that in the future, if I need to override any method (e.g get_queryset() ) I will know whether to put in "self" or not. I don't know how python looks for method/attributes nor what `classmethod` decorator does